# Calculating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{nx^n}{4n^2-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form

I would appreciate any help calculating the series.  And determine where does the series converge uniformly.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{nx^n}{4n^2-1}} $$

Comment: Perhaps partial fractions and $4n^2-1=(2n+1)(2n-1)$ might help

Comment: Julio, do NOT deface the post by replacing it with something non-sensical. The question has been answered, and breaking the link between the answers and the question in this way is against the rule. This rule will be strictly enforced. Actually any established user who has earned the privilege to edit posts will do so. It is all part of the model we are operating on. I encourage you to familiarize with it by browsing the site. You will learn it quickly enough!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. You may write
$$
\frac{nx^n}{4n^2-1}=\frac{x^n}{4 (2 n-1)}+\frac{x^n}{4 (2 n+1)}
$$ and one may recall

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{u^{2n+1}}{2 n+1}=\frac12 \log\left(\frac{1+u}{1-u}\right), \qquad |u|<1.
> $$